# Question about Chaos Theory and Relation to Game...

Tags: chaos-theory

I am working on a project (for social sciences) and I found a game, Parable of Polygons ([link](https://ncase.me/polygons/))

I observe chaotic behavior, but am unable to mathematically explain this. Are there any ideas on how the above game can also incorporate ideas of chaos theory (mathematically)?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that game models chaos in any formal mathematical sense, though I might be wrong.

But to answer a question behind your question - I think writing about this game and what it claims to teach might make an outstanding social sciences project. There's no need to pursue the formal mathematics to do that. It might in fact be a distraction.

Comment: So the system is stochastic? Are there any mathematical tools that I can use to analyze a stochastic system, as I also need to have a solid mathematical background for the social science aspect. I can easily write the relation to sociology, but I posted here because I wanted to understand the math behind this process... Any articles would also be great help.

Comment: The page deals with the stochastic issues by simulating them. Whether there is a closed form analysis that tells you the long term behavior depends on the precise formulation, and then some hard work. I doubt that's in the literature anywhere. You could write the authors and ask.

Comment: To me it looks slightly similar to models in statistical physics (like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model) one): you have some sort of a graph or lattice, and you can put 'elements' of different types in the vertices of this graph. However, in statistical physics (as far as I see) you have some kind of a functional which is often minimized and parameters which force specific order of 'elements', and I don't see such functional from the get go for the model which might correspond to this game.